# How to encrypt each value in a column in a database table with different keys

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I have my own symmetric encryption algorithm used to encrypt/decrypt data. when encrypting a column in my database table using a fixed(static) key, it produces the same ciphertexts to the same plaintext(deterministic). How to encrypt each value in the column with a different key using c#.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: @AntonínLejsek A Salt has nothing to do with encryption.

Answer (score 0):

*"I have my **own** symmetric encryption algorithm"* - this part of your question makes me queasy.  If you mean one that you've created yourself, you should probably fix this first.

What you need is a different mode of operation.  Currently you're using ECB, which is bad.  Aside from the fact that it produces predictable ciphertexts, it has a plethora of other security related pitfalls that make it a poor choice in general.

What you want to use is a mode that introduces an IV or nonce.  This will fix your initial problem as well as improving security in general.  CBC is probably the most common.  An authenticated mode like GCM is even better.  I suggest you research modes of operation carefully, and the requirements to use different modes securely.

Comment: my algorithm is a stream cipher algorithm

Answer (score 0):

[The Counter Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)), CTR is another alternative to Luke's answer. You can use the row counter as the counter in the CTR mode. Which can prevent data swap attack in columns. You must store just the IV somewhere. In, GCM mode, you have to store the authentication tags, too. If you don't need authentication stick to CTR, GCM uses CTR inside.

I would like to add that, if you want to query over this column, once you get away from the ECB mode, you can no longer execute `SELECT` `WHERE` with this column.

As a general example, you can look at [CryptDB](https://dspace.mit.edu/openaccess-disseminate/1721.1/74107) to see that which queries can be executed on encrypted data, and how. CryptDB utilize, ECB (equality), CBC (randomized), OPE (Order Preserving Ecnryption for ORDER BY ) and Paillier for aggregates.